# Unity tile jump without physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create jump from tile to tile without using unity physics. For now i have a working solution which is working perfectly, but i want a improvement which i can't code myself.

In these 2 pictures ill show what i have and what i want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CxBf.png)

My goal is my player to be able to jump again when jump is almost finished (which i made but full with bugs), and this second third etc jump in a row to be as high as my archeigh variable.

Here is my code, hope u guys understand my problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerControls controls;

    Vector3 _startPosition;
    Vector3 lastPosition;
    Quaternion targetRotation;
    bool jumping = false;
    public AudioSource audioListener;
    public AudioClip JumpSound;
    public float rayLenght = 1.4f;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    float parabola = 0f;
    float _stepScale;
    float _progress;
    public float speed;
    public float arcHeight;
    Vector3 targetDestination;
    private float targetArcHeight;

    private bool ableToJump = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new PlayerControls();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        controls.Main.Movement.performed += ctx => Move(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>());
        _startPosition = transform.position;
        targetArcHeight = arcHeight;
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Move(Vector2 direction)
    {
        if (ableToJump)
        {
            _progress = 0f;
           // parabola = 0f;
            ableToJump = false;
            _startPosition = transform.position;

            CalculateArcHeight();

            Vector3 movement = new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.y);

            targetDestination = lastPosition + movement;
            lastPosition = targetDestination;
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(_startPosition, targetDestination);
            _stepScale = speed / distance;

            audioListener.PlayOneShot(JumpSound);
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDestination - _startPosition);
            jumping = true;

            
        }


    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (jumping)
        {
            
            // Increment our progress from 0 at the start, to 1 when we arrive.
            _progress = Mathf.Min(_progress + Time.deltaTime * _stepScale, 1.0f);

            // Turn this 0-1 value into a parabola that goes from 0 to 1, then back to 0.
            parabola = 1.0f - 4.0f * (_progress - 0.5f) * (_progress - 0.5f);

            // Travel in a straight line from our start position to the target.        
            Vector3 nextPos = Vector3.Lerp(_startPosition, targetDestination, _progress);

            
            // Then add a vertical arc in excess of this.
            nextPos.y += parabola * targetArcHeight;

            transform.position = nextPos;

            // Arrived
            if (_progress >= 0.6f)
            {
                ableToJump = true;
            }

        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 10f * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    private void CalculateArcHeight()
    {
        float currentHeight = transform.position.y;
        targetArcHeight = targetArcHeight - currentHeight;

    }

}
```

P.S. My rotation sometimes also stuck on strange x rotation.
Thanks in advance

i made it to double jump but cannot calculate new height to be 1(my archheight).

Comment: I don’t understand why you want what you want, but it seems like you are asking people to write code for you. If you have written it yourself and want help solving problems, that is fine, but stackoverflow is not a site for asking other people to write code. You should be more descriptive of the exact problem you are having.

Comment: I think i said that i tried to make it what i want and where is my problem. If not. The problem is that when i reset parabola and progress on 80% of progress my double jump works but my player goes to Y value like 0.8 or 0.9, not 1, like is my archeigh target.

Comment: Is the code you wrote the working version that needs improvement or the attempted improved version>

Comment: I think you're going to make things harder for yourself by opting out of physics jumping if you're not sure how to code to begin with.

I don't know anything about your game, but if I were to steer you into any direction, I'd say have a look at using a sin wave with delta time to control the height of the character through the jump during a measure of time.

I'd think long and hard about why you're opting out of the physics before you shoe horn into any of that though.  Applying upward force and using the engines gravity, and collision to stop falling is not bad practice for jumping.

Comment: My code is working for single jump. CalculateTargetHeight() is where i try to calculate my new target for y. And if you uncomment variable parabola in move function ull get to the point where my double jump works but new height is not 1 as i wanted.

Comment: @Krausladeni tried with physics first, but in my case without physics is the best solution. Just need to understand how to calculate things to make second jump to go same height as first.